# DBCC Command Not Working Inside Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dbcc

I have below query. Logically, the procedure `usp_mytran` should RESEED the Identity to 1 for table `dbo.Sales`. But the last query is returning different values for *Max_ID_Value* and *Current_Seed_Value*. Can anyone please explain why DBCC command is not working inside procedure?

```
USE tempdb

--  Create table 
CREATE  TABLE dbo.Sales
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Address VARCHAR(200))
GO

--  Procedure to Populate data into dbo.Sales
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_mytran 
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT dbo.Sales
            ( Address )
    VALUES  ( 'Dwarka, Delhi' );

    --  Delete it for some reason
    DELETE FROM dbo.Sales;

    --  Code to check max ID value, and verify it again IDENTITY SEED
    DECLARE @MaxValue INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),1) FROM dbo.Sales)
    IF @MaxValue IS NOT NULL AND @MaxValue <> IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Sales')
        DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'tempdb.dbo.Sales', RESEED, @MaxValue );
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

--  Ideally, this should RESEED the Identity of dbo.Sales table.
EXEC usp_mytran

--  Max_ID_Value & Current_Seed_Value should be same
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),1) AS Max_ID_Value, IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Sales') AS Current_Seed_Value FROM dbo.Sales
```

Comment: Please do execute procedure `usp_mytran` more than once to note the difference in values of *Max_ID_Value* and *Current_Seed_Value*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is working as expected inside stored procedure: Rollback tran will rollback the checkident value - that is what happening in the code

```
--  Procedure to Populate data into dbo.Sales
alter PROCEDURE usp_mytran 
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT dbo.Sales
            ( Address )
    VALUES  ( 'Dwarka, Delhi' );

    --  Delete it for some reason
    DELETE FROM dbo.Sales;

    --  Code to check max ID value, and verify it again IDENTITY SEED
    DECLARE @MaxValue INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),1) FROM dbo.Sales)
    IF @MaxValue IS NOT NULL AND @MaxValue <> IDENT_CURRENT('test.dbo.Sales')
        DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'test.dbo.Sales', RESEED, @MaxValue );
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

If you check ident_current now it shows 2 and on the next run it shows 4 etc because of **ROLLBACK TRANSACTION**

Now check after multiple executions "EXEC usp_mytran"

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('test.dbo.Sales')
```

You will see that checkident will not reset.

If we remove that transaction then CHECKIDENT will reseed to 1.

Commented transaction below

```
--  Procedure to Populate data into dbo.Sales
alter PROCEDURE usp_mytran 
AS
BEGIN
    --BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT dbo.Sales
            ( Address )
    VALUES  ( 'Dwarka, Delhi' );

    --  Delete it for some reason
    DELETE FROM dbo.Sales;

    --  Code to check max ID value, and verify it again IDENTITY SEED
    DECLARE @MaxValue INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),1) FROM dbo.Sales)
    IF @MaxValue IS NOT NULL AND @MaxValue <> IDENT_CURRENT('test.dbo.Sales')
        DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'test.dbo.Sales', RESEED, @MaxValue );
    --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Now check after multiple executions "EXEC usp_mytran"

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('test.dbo.Sales')
```

You will see the reseed value as '1'

Check for below example as well...

[Can we rollback to original state after we have used DBCC CHECKIDENT to restart Identity column count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861642/can-we-rollback-to-original-state-after-we-have-used-dbcc-checkident-to-restart)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for answering my own question. As pointed by @Kannan Kandasamy, it is the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` code that is reverting back the work done by `DBCC CHECKIDENT`. So to make it work, I have created a job with name `Reseed_Sales` containing code to RESEED Identity for table `dbo.Sales`. Below is the final query for procedure `usp_mytran`.

```
--  Procedure to Populate data into dbo.Sales
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_mytran 
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT dbo.Sales
            ( Address )
    VALUES  ( 'Dwarka, Delhi' );

    --  Delete it for some reason
    DELETE FROM dbo.Sales;

    --  Code to check max ID value, and verify it again IDENTITY SEED
    DECLARE @MaxValue INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),1) FROM dbo.Sales)
    IF @MaxValue IS NOT NULL AND @MaxValue <> IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Sales')
        EXEC msdb..sp_start_job @job_name = 'Reseed_Sales'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but using identity doesn't look like the right solution. Your code has various issues under concurrency.

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith, please check question [Identity key counter increment by one although it is in TRY Catch and Transaction is roll-backed ? SSMS 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013274/identity-key-counter-increment-by-one-although-it-is-in-try-catch-and-transactio/40014054#40014054). Requirement was *if TRY block fails, then RESEED the Identity value in CATCH block, and rollback the transaction*. So this is what I am trying to achieve by keeping `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` and within it tying to RESEED the identity using sql agent job all from within Procedure.

Comment: If you want a column that doesn't have gaps `IDENTITY` is not the right tool for the job. You should realize this when you are having to do crazy things like spawn SQL agent jobs inside a simple CRUD procedure. Under concurrency you will certainly find your approach doesn't work anyway.